# Swift 3 version of Swift 2 code no longer affects byte array when drawing over it

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am converting some Swift 2 code into Swift 3. Here's the code in Swift 2

```
if self.maskImagePixelData != nil {
    if let context:CGContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(
            &maskImagePixelData!,
            Int(inputImage.size.width),
            Int(inputImage.size.height),
            8,
            Int(inputImage.size.width),
            CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
            CGImageAlphaInfo.None.rawValue ) {
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
        CGContextSetLineJoin(context, CGLineJoin.Round)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, CGFloat(touchRadius * 2))
        if remove {
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.PlusDarker)
        } else {
            CGContextSetGrayStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0)
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.PlusLighter)
        }
        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
        for line:(start:CGPoint, end:CGPoint) in lines {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, line.start.x, inputImage.size.height - line.start.y)
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, line.end.x, inputImage.size.height - line.end.y)
        }
        CGContextAddPath(context, path)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
}
```

And here's how I have converted it into Swift 3

```
if self.maskImagePixelData != nil {
    if let context:CGContext = CGContext(
            data: &maskImagePixelData!,
            width: Int(inputImage.size.width),
            height: Int(inputImage.size.height),
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bytesPerRow: Int(inputImage.size.width),
            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue ) {
        context.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
        context.setLineJoin(CGLineJoin.round)
        context.setLineWidth(CGFloat(touchRadius * 2))
        if remove {
            context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.plusDarker)
        } else {
            context.setStrokeColor(gray: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.plusLighter)
        }
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        for line:(start:CGPoint, end:CGPoint) in lines {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: line.start.x, y: inputImage.size.height - line.start.y))
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: line.end.x, y: inputImage.size.height - line.end.y))
        }
        context.addPath(path)
        context.strokePath()
    }
}
```

In the Swift 2 version the `[UInt8]` `self.maskImagePixelData` is changed - i.e. the code manipulates the values in the byte array, while in the Swift 3 code they are left unchanged.

This looks like the correct translation from Swift 2 to Swift 3; what am I missing? Why isn't the byte array overwritten by the Swift 3 code?

Comment: You probably wanted to call `path.addLine` instead of the second `path.move` in the Swift 3 snippet.

Comment: Doh! Excellent, thank you. I won't tell you how long I've stared at those lines trying to work out what was wrong! In my defence the real code has some comment lines in which may have been distracting me.